# How to call a JS function at the page load of Docusaurus site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, yarnpkg, docusaurus

I need to load a custom JS function I wrote at the beginning of the page load in a Docusaurus documentation site.

What have I tried so far?

**Attempt #1: Appending the script to the index.js file (.\src\components\HomepageFeatures\index.js)**

This attempt worked well during testing but then `yarn` was not able to build the project anymore. The error was as follows:

> [ERROR] Docusaurus server-side rendering could not render static page
> with path /. [INFO] It looks like you are using code that should run
> on the client-side only. To get around it, try using `<BrowserOnly>`
> (https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core/#browseronly) or
> `ExecutionEnvironment`
> (https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core/#executionenvironment). It
> might also require to wrap your client code in `useEffect` hook and/or
> import a third-party library dynamically (if any).

**Attempt #2:** To counter the issue presented during my first attempt, I created a separate (.js) file in **(./src/js/myfunction.js)** and then tried to load that file. To keep this question short, I will add a sample script below to showcase the issue:

```
import BrowserOnly from '@docusaurus/BrowserOnly';

<BrowserOnly>

window.onload = function() {
  alert("Welcome!");
}

</BrowserOnly>
```

Then I went to the Docusaurus config file and added the following:

```
scripts: [
    {
      src: './src/js/myfunction.js',
      async: false,
    },
],
```

The site was built successfully this time, but the function was not getting loaded. I tried to call the function as well but still, I was getting nothing. I think I don't understand how the `<BrowserOnly>` feature works or I am missing something else.

Your help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue eventually by adjusting the custom-made JS file as follows:

```
import ExecutionEnvironment from '@docusaurus/ExecutionEnvironment';

if (ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM) {
    // My own custom JS code.
}
```

Thereafter, I loaded that custom JS file from the config file (docusaurus.config.js) by adding the following:

```
clientModules: [
    require.resolve('./path-to-custom-code/custom-code.js'),
],
```

This has been mentioned briefly in the documentation but it wasn't clear at all. The documentation of Docusaurus requires more elaboration and examples.

You can view it here though:
https://docusaurus.io/docs/advanced/client#client-modules

If anyone has a better approach, please add it to this post. Thanks!